# SharePoint 2013 search "documents with no content"

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

I have uploaded two documents along with metadata in a document library for example say

1. Test1.docx with no content (empty document).
2. Test2.docx with some content.

When I search for both Test1.docx or Test2.docx Test1.docx is never displayed. Test2.docx is showing up correctly in search results. Even if I search with Test1.docx's metadata its not showing up. Looks like SharePoint search ignores documents with empty content. Is this expected behavior? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I can search the document with no contents.

You could do a full crawl, then search, compare the result.